# JavaMail, adding line breaks in plain text emails

Tags: email, jakarta-mail

I am using java mail api to send "text/plain" content-type emails over smtp. I am using email templates that are stored in database. In order to put line breaks in the email body, I am using `\r\n`. However, when the email is received the `\r\n` are not converted to line breaks instead they appear as text `\r\n`.

For example:

```
This line is followed by a carriage return.\r\nThis is a new line.
```

in the template email body appears in the received email as

```
This line is followed by a carriage return.\r\nThis is a new line.
```

instead of

```
This line is followed by a carriage return.

This is a new line.
```

I have tried using just `\n` and that too does not work. How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I get same problem,
And when I add "space" before newline, It's work
But that's mean create tag " pre " for each line.

Answer (score 0):

If the template contains the line breaks as separate backslash and 'n' characters, you're going to need to do something to convert it to a real "newline" character.  Ditto \r.  Better would be to store the template with real carriage return and newline characters to begin with.